# Is forcing power through a faulting board a good diagnostic tool?

Tags: short-circuit, repair, motherboard

I was researching how to diagnose what SMD was shorting on a laptops motherboard when I found an unusual diagnostic test. The video I came across
showed a tech using a variable power supply to force a voltage through the board, then he used a thermal camera to identify the location of the short. This struck me as a rather risky process. Is this a good method to identify faulty components or is this more likely going to damage the board?

See this video: https://youtu.be/HLa3YoonVzE?t=5m58s

Comment: Define "risky". Given that the device is dead already and searching for the shorted part "manually" can take so long as to make repair uneconomical, it's probably worth the shot ?

Comment: I would define risky as it's a extreme method that could risk damaging the board even more, granted I'm not really versed in methods of detecting faulty SMD components, I feel forcing voltage is a bit on the higher likelihood of blowing up more components

Comment: it's dumb if your working on a board for the space shuttle, but in a consumer triage situation where it's a fix/replace question, it's hard to see the harm of breaking the broken more. You can also limit the power with this method to avoid an instant burnout, so it's not as risky as it might sound.

Comment: Heh... thermal camera. Real men look for shorts by fingertips (and in some cases, by lips...)

Comment: @fraxinus Perhaps, but people whose time is money use a thermal camera ;)

Comment: risky is relative, if I have a pile of 100 boards to test to suss out a design flaw I can burn a few, if I only have one and its the only one to diagnose, well, not so much value. Yes its common, and fun ,:P

Comment: The old method was to freeze the board (with some ozone depleting "freeze spray") and then watch the shorted trace melt the frost first.

Comment: This is actually a method I've used to detect the problem in a faulty integrated circuit, using some specially formulated liquid crystal that goes transparent at just a few degrees above room temperature. Self-heating of the die made the liquid crystal transparent exactly above where the flaw in the silicon was, and a bit of analysis of the design files later and we had a working theory on how to make the next revision work this time--and so far, it looks like the next revision did indeed work, though I haven't had a chance to fully test it yet.

Comment: Funny story - I worked at a company that included a PCB fab. My boss took over the bare-board test department. On the first day he wandered in, he saw a car battery by the wall. They were using it for blowing shorts. One of the products was a backplane for a very large global telecoms company for use in their 3G base-stations.  The battery was removed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is a fairly standard technique when a node has a short circuit (low impedance) failure. The reason it is safe is that all of the current flows through the faulty device.

You do have to have some understanding of the board you are testing. And you need to avoid applying excessive voltage to the node you are testing. The voltage should not be higher than the normal operating voltage for that node.

In some cases boards have multiple voltage regulators, and there could be sequencing requirements for them. It may not be safe to power 1.8 V while 3.3 V is unpowered or something like that (just a made-up example). But if the voltage is kept below 0.5 V or so there should be no problem even if there is a sequencing requirement.

Some people may question, if it is a short circuit, why does it get hot? The answer is that "short circuit" really means much lower than normal resistance or impedance. Even if it is 100 mOhms, if 2 Amps goes through 0.1 Ohms, and the component is small, it will lead to a lot of heat. Also, traces may get hot if they are not designed to carry 2 Amps. So the faulty component or the traces leading to it will likely get hot.

Answer (score 5):

It's a good method in my opinion. The only difference between what you write and the preferred way is that you'd probably use a bench power supply with variable current limit. So, initially, you might set the current limit to 300 mA and, if you got no-joy from the thermal camera then you might bump it up to an amp.

I'm recommending a current limited power supply so that you don't end up burning copper tracks in case the short is very, very zero ohm-ish. In effect, the current limit keeps the PCB copper from harm and you should be able to see any warming copper tracks quite easily with the thermal camera.

If a thermal camera is good enough for spotting warm components in normal operation it's good enough (with a little care) for spotting shorted ICs.

Comment: And set the power supply's voltage low, to 1V or so. So when the shorted part blows up completely because of the procedure, and the short is gone, the voltage doesn't shoot up and fry everything. Learned to remember that the hard way :/

Comment: @Unimportant yeah, suddenly there's 30 volts and kaboom.

Comment: @Unimportant, there are some fields in which wisdom always comes from pain :D

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the other answers, when it is impossible to determine the shorted component(s) via thermal method, another method is to use a precision resistance measurement.

Many multimeters have an "extended precision range" for resistance. Put yours in that mode, or use a multimeter or milliohmmeter with high precision, and trace the shorts through the board.  The lowest reading(s) will likely be the culprit(s).

An alternative is to apply the regular *voltage* at some limited current.  Then probe for voltages across those traces.  The lowest volts = lowest Ohms.

*I once found a shorted MLCC ceramic bypass cap this way, when I didn't have an IR camera and the short was such low-resistance that traces would heat up before the short would.  The difference in resistance on the cap, to the end of the trace, was only ~5 milliohms, so a really good meter is needed.*

Comment: Polar Toneohm uses this to identify shorts to a power-plane. It's a bloody fantastic bit of kit that I used to have on my bench, in a former life.

Comment: The [Toneohm](https://www.polarinstruments.com/products/toneohm/toneohm_950.html) is indeed very interesting; thanks for sharing.

Comment: thanks for bothering to dig out the link, that I didn't!

Answer (score 2):

It depends what is the purpose of diagnosing it. Sure, it may cause damage, but there already might be damage when power is first applied, even before you know that there is a problem and can see what is overheating. How risky it is and what possible damage it could cause depends what the problem is and where. Usually you would do some measurements and determine if forcibly powering a board is still a good option or bad one. There is no one true answer to this. If you have one or only a few prototype boards, it may be beneficial to bring up the faulty one, even partially.

As a side note, if the problem is a short on a PCB track, some moderate amount of current with low voltage can burn the short circuit clear.

Answer (score 2):

A lot depends on the particulars of the board under question.

If this is a PCB in a $100 power supply for a desktop PC then sure, go ahead and pump some current through the fault and see if you can locate the fault or maybe it will burn open.  If things don't work out, then worst case is you're out $100 for a new PS.

If this is a $250,000 board for a space application, then there's some engineering judgement involved.  For example, what's the cost, both for a new assembly plus the cost of the schedule hit if you don't repair the board?  What kind of risk is the program willing to accept if the forcing current method does allow you to locate and repair the short, but you're not sure whether or not you've induced any latent defect or weakness into the board, something that may not show up until years later.  That is, is this going to become a Challenger O-ring situation.

Years ago we had a multilayer PCB (12, 14 layers) that was reworked by drilling through the board to add a through hole component.  This was a PCB with both a 5V and GND plane.  Well in the drilling process (yes, we used very sharp drill bits) the copper was smeared between the 5 V and GND planes, creating a low resistance short.  In the system, this board was plugged into a passive backplane and powered by a 200 A power supply.  It didn't take long for the available current to heat the board to the point where more copper became part of the short and we ended up with a charred board that had to be scrapped.  I do not remember if the board actually started to burn or not.